Counting points in an open3d Voxel
I'm trying to count points inside a VoxelGrid's Voxels with little success. After a long debugging session and reading this thread my issue is most likely with the different indexing in the voxel_down_sample_and_trace() method and the VoxelGrid.create_from_point_cloud_within_bounds() method. My general idea was that If I use these 2 methods with the same given bounding box, it would result in the same VoxelGrid being inspected, but that is incorrect as the indexes to the individual Voxels differ.
Does anyone have a solution for this?
Here's reproduction of what I'm trying to do, with a funky visualization that aims to show that there is a problem (this is the only way I could easily show Voxels one-by-one, since adding Voxels to an empty grid did not show anything upon displaying)
import numpy as np
import open3d as o3d
import copy

# Define the parameters
num_points = 200  # Number of random points
cube_size = 5  # Size of the cube
voxel_size = 0.5

voxel_points_index_array = []
voxel_point_count_array = []

# Generate random points for the first point cloud
points_cloud1 = cube_size * np.random.rand(num_points, 3)
pcd1 = o3d.geometry.PointCloud()
pcd1.points = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(points_cloud1)

min_bound = pcd1.get_min_bound()
max_bound = pcd1.get_max_bound()

voxel_grid1 = o3d.geometry.VoxelGrid.create_from_point_cloud_within_bounds(pcd1, voxel_size=voxel_size, min_bound=min_bound max_bound=max_bound)
                                                                                                                                                     
pcd_copy1 = copy.deepcopy(pcd1)

_, _, points_index_list = pcd_copy1.voxel_down_sample_and_trace(voxel_size=voxel_size, min_bound=min_bound,max_bound=max_bound)

for i, idx in enumerate(points_index_list):
    voxel_points_index_array.append(np.asarray(idx))
    voxel_point_count_array.append(len(idx))

voxs = voxel_grid1.get_voxels()

for n in range(10):
    vg = copy.deepcopy(voxel_grid1)
    for i in range(n, len(voxs), 1):
        vg.remove_voxel(voxs[i].grid_index)
    print(points_index_list[n])
    print(voxel_point_count_array[n])
    pcd2 = pcd1.select_by_index(points_index_list[n])
    o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([vg, pcd2])

